# The Lxss folder in windows for Bash on Ubuntu on Windows is missing

Tags: windows

### Problem and Hypothesis

It's a pretty simple problem, I just can't find the Lxss folder in LocalAppData which is suppose to store files from the Bash on Ubuntu on Windows.

I only see one of two possibilities for why this is. Either Windows moved the Lxss folder in an update for Bash on Ubuntu on Windows, or it is an error specific to my system that has caused Windows not to create the Lxss folder. I don't think this is the possibility though because it is a fresh install of windows.

---

### Steps I have tried:

1. Unhiding files and folders in windows
2. Shutting down Bash on Ubuntu on Windows and refreshing my LocalAppData
3. Restarting Windows and checking my LocalAppData

---

Screenshots of LocalAppData:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

I can add more information if needed.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You have to uncheck "Hide protected operating system files (recommended)" in the folder options window.

Comment: You can also simply enter `%APPDATA%\..\Local\Lxss` in the explorer location bar. However [Do not change Linux files using Windows Apps and tools](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/)

Answer (score 66):

It was actually moved in the latest release to :

`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\`

See [this blog post from WLS git repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2578)

Comment: I use debian, lxss is in `c:/windows/syswow64` and c:/windows/system32

Answer (score 3):

The selected solution is old and valid for Ubuntu only.

For Opensuse leap-15.1 users this is different:

- > C:\Users\"yourusername"\AppData\Local\Packages\46932SUSE.openSUSE-Leap-15-1_022rs5jcyhyac\LocalState\rootfs

The numbers will differ from version to version and may change in the future.

The trick is to look for something related to Linux in C:\Users\"yourusername">\AppData\Local\Packages\"xxxxx"\LocalState\root\fs

where

- "yourusername" is your Windows 10 user login
- "xxxxx" is a custom name related to the Linux distribution installed

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of Windows Fall Creator Update, I found it in `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\lxss\`