# AppData/Local/lsxx folder about Bash on Windows disappear

Tags: bash, windows-10, directory, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I can't figure out why that folder is disappeared from a moment to an other!
I'm learning to use Git and I was trying some commands, then I decided to close the bash. When I restarted it, Bash give me `bash: /mnt/c/Users/Andrea: File or directory doesn't exist` and if I browse in AppData/Local the lsxx folder doesn't exist anymore.

I've already tried to:

- unhiding folders in windows
- uninstall and reinstall the bash functionality from windows control panel
- use command Lxrun.exe /uninstall and then Lxrune.exe /install from prompt (admin mode). Procedure finished without error.

but the folder can't be created anymore. I think this post is similar but it has no solution at all: [Squid dev's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39886862/the-lxss-folder-in-windows-for-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-is-missing)
Can someone figure it out?

Thank you in advance

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out! The `mv` command is buggy for some reason explained here [github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/705](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/705). So I followed the proposed solution and resetted the bash.
For some strange reason the lxss folder disappeard from windows explorer (even if I show hidden folders), but it's still reachable inserting the full path in the address bar through: `C:\Users\your_user\AppData\Local\lxss`